# Camera view pointer

Tags: camera

how i change the pointer of camera view, i'm explain. in my blender, the camera view is vertical by default and not horizontall. as you can see the arrow is on the vertical side, it's supposed should be in horizontal side, thanks for you help!

pdta: sorry my english is not so good.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera gizmo just displays the ratio of Resolution X to Y.

Make X higher then Y and you'll get horizontal side

[Render to print](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render_to_Print/) is the coolest addon to control output dimensions and it can swap layout in one click

[image: Dimensions]